# ILOG Gantt and windows 8

Tags: windows-8, gantt-chart, ilog

Is someone know if ILOG Gantt (.net) is compatible with Windows 8? I didn't find the information on the IBM website..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has discontinued this product:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/net/redirect/

I am representing a company that provides an alternative product which also works with Windows 8. May be it is worthwhile to have a look here.
http://blog.netronic.com/migration-offer-ibm-ilog-gantt-net-customers-partners

Answer (score 1):

This is an older app that appears to be owned by IBM, and it looks as if the last modified date on their page is August 2010.  If you have a IBM support account then you would use the link: [IBM ILOG](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418886) to find out.  If you know the version of .NET then you can check the coverage at: [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

This question was correctly tagged as Windows 8, but my recommendation is to get the answer from IBM directly.